# Can't visualize RaySensor in Gazebo 1.5

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi all,

I'm working through the tutorials with the aim of learning to write my own ROS plugins to control models.

In the [Control Model tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.3/intermediate/control_model), the example has true for the ray sensor. However, I can't see the ray when I load the world file. Does this happen for everyone?

Also: part 2 of my question on the tutorial is [here](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2062/control-model-tutorial-sensor-isnt-attached/).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2061/can%27t-visualize-raysensor-in-gazebo-1.5/) by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 175 on 2013-03-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Make sure you use the correct tutorials. Your link goes to a Gazebo 1.3 tutorial, but the title of this question is for Gazebo 1.5.

Also, make sure that <always_on> is set to true. Otherwise the laser will be disabled until someone, such as ROS, subscribes to the laser data.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on 2013-04-09**:
I'm not sure what's changed -- but I've gone through, copied from the 1.5 tutorial, and it seems to work.  I think I was using the 1.3 tutorial because the 1.3 set had some stuff the 1.5 set didn't yet have.

**Comment by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on 2013-04-09**:
Also, thanks for the inspiration -- in checking out the <always_on> tags in the sdf documentation, I found out about the <update_rate> tags which allowed me to solve this: http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2086/has-anybody-gotten-the-contact-sensor-example-to/?answer=2303#post-id-2303 problem.